# Power BI Api to get Last Refresh time

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to get the **Last Refresh time** for a dataset from Power BI portal.
I want to insert that data into a table.
But it seems there is no API available for the same. 
Can anyone help me with a way to do that?

Comment: Provide more information about your setup. What's your data source?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in 2 different ways:

1. You can create a blank query and use the following M query to create a single-cell table:

   ```
   let
      Source = #table(type table[Last Refresh=datetime], {{DateTime.LocalNow()}})
   in
      Source
   ```

   [image]

A nd then you can use the `Card visual` and drag in the column to show it. You can rename the field to remove the default aggregation. (It doesn't matter since there is only one row of data anyways)

[image]

The value will be recalculated each time the data is refreshed.

2. You can also achieve it by adding a `calculated column` (Refresh data Column) in the model with the formula `=NOW()`

   Then add a new `Measure`

   ```
   Last Refresh Date :=MAX(Table[Last Refresh Column])
   ```

   Since calculated columns are calculated only on model refresh, it will make sure the calculation is right.